# How to get a nested element in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am struggling with the syntax required to grab some *hrefs* in a `<td>`.
The `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` elements don't have any classes or ids.

If I wanted to grab the *anchor* in this example, what would I need?

```html
<tr>
    <td><a>...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As per the docs, you first make a parse tree:

```
import BeautifulSoup
html = "<html><body><tr><td><a href='foo'/></td></tr></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

and then you search in it, for example for `<a>` tags whose immediate parent is a `<td>`:

```
for ana in soup.findAll('a'):
  if ana.parent.name == 'td':
    print ana["href"]
```

Comment: @Greyshack, works fine for me (using the current release of course, 6+ years after the original post -- pip install beautifulsoup4, and then of course the module name is now bs4) -- print 'foo', as required. It's of course impossible to offer you any help based on as vague a description of your problem as "doesnt [sic] work"!-)

Answer (score 32):

Something like this?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
anchors = [td.find('a') for td in soup.findAll('td')]
```

That should find the first "a" inside each "td" in the html you provide.  You can tweak `td.find` to be more specific or else use `findAll` if you have several links inside each td.

UPDATE: re Daniele's comment, if you want to make sure you don't have any `None`'s in the list, then you could modify the list comprehension thus:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
anchors = [a for a in (td.find('a') for td in soup.findAll('td')) if a]
```

Which basically just adds a check to see if you have an actual element returned by `td.find('a')`.

Comment: that's very smart! but if 'a' is not present, it would include a None into the anchors list? how can I populate the anchors list only the actual 'a's skypping the Nones?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question to deal with removing None's from list.