# BeautifulSoup: How to get nested divs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Given the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="category1" id="foo">
      <div class="category2" id="bar">
            <div class="category3">
            </div>
            <div class="category4">
                 <div class="category5"> test
                 </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to extract the word `test` from `<div class="category5"> test` using BeautifulSoup i.e how to deal with nested divs? I tried to lookup on the Internet but I didn't find any case that treat an easy to grasp example so I set up this one. Thanks.

Comment: What about nested divs? What are you trying to extract, and why do nested divs form an obstacle to that goal? You can just search for those specific divs, nested or not.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058599/how-to-get-a-nested-element-in-beautiful-soup

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the problem come from the fact that the divs are nested into each other because when I mysoup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'category5'}) the return value is None !

Comment: @Andy it's not a duplicate read the other question you linked us too. Here we are using attrs={...} the solution is different when you have a pure tag like <td>

Comment: @torr: no, if you cannot find the div with that search then it is *not present in the tree*.

Comment: @torr: what version of BeautifulSoup are you using? What is the actual HTML? If you are using BeautifulSoup, do you have `lxml` installed?

Comment: @Andy: this has **nothing** to do with nesting. The OP cannot find a specific div, but the search is correct. Which means that the div is not there, which could be caused by several different things, not least of all by the version of BeautifulSoup and what parser is being used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**xpath** should be the straight forward answer, however this is not supported in `BeautifulSoup`.

#### Updated: with a BeautifulSoup solution

To do so, given that you know the **class** and element (**div**) in this case, you can use a `for/loop` with `attrs` to get what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<html>
<body>
<div class="category1" id="foo">
      <div class="category2" id="bar">
            <div class="category3">
            </div>
            <div class="category4">
                 <div class="category5"> test
                 </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'''

content = BeautifulSoup(html)

for div in content.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'category5'}):
    print div.text

test
```

I have no problem extracting the text from your html sample, like @MartijnPieters suggested, you will need to find out why your **div** element is missing.

#### Another update

As you're missing `lxml` as a parser for `BeautifulSoup`, that's why None was returned as you haven't parsed anything to start with. Install `lxml` should solve your issue.

You may consider using `lxml` or similar which supports **xpath**, dead easy if you ask me.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(html) # or etree.parse from source
tree.xpath('.//div[@class="category5"]/text()')
[' test\n                 ']
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I understand OP states `BeautifulSoup`, but doesn't mention if another library will be accepted. I may edit and add a solution for using `BeautifulSoup` too.

Comment: The problem is that the div is *not present in the parsed tree*. Why that is is unanswerable because the OP has not given us the details required to diagnose. The assumption that it has anything to do with nesting is wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you're quite right. OP has confused with nested elements whereas clearly the technique needed is to add *attrs* to match the given **div** element with a class **category5**. Answer updated.

Comment: I got an `type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'RobustHTMLParser'` also shouldn't it be `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @torr, it's about how you installed your modules, what's your version of `BeautifulSoup`? if `from bs4 ...` works for you that's fine too. Also, I'm really suggesting you switch to other library as `BeautifulSoup` is rather not maintained and slower in performance compared to other libraries

Comment: @Anzel I am using BeautifulSoup 4 and I installed it via pip. How can I use RobustHTMLParser()? What are some cool alternatives to BeautifulSoup? Thanks

Comment: @torr, alright I'm dumb you're on `bs4' of course, i'm using **3.2.1** which is even behind your version. I will edit the answer for `bs4`

Comment: @torr, answer updated for **bs4**, it's even simpler than my version. Depending on the task you're doing, be it Scraping? or just one-off parsing content and grab the information. For scraping project, I recommend **Scrapy**, and simple parsing, just use **lxml** is fine as it comes as a parser for `BeautifulSoup` anyway

Comment: @Anzel The code is what I was using so far but it returns nothing even though I know the div is present in the file, I have the source but nothing is returned.

Comment: @torr, like Martijn Pieters suggested before, that's a main reason why your parsing fail. Are you getting the **html** from a source (like a file, requests content), or from a string?

Comment: @torr, you may be missing `lxml` as a parser for `BeautifulSoup`. Can you quickly try in your console `python -c "import lxml"` and see if it fails?

Comment: You are right, lxml is missing. I am installing it right now, keep you updated

Comment: lxml is now installed but the output is still lacking :(

Comment: I figured out what isn't working, I actually need to be logged on the website I am trying to scrap. Thanks you so much for your help, I learned a lot today.

Comment: are you sure `lxml` is working properly? try my second answer using `lxml` and see if it works

Comment: @torr, lol ok! so it's the source you're parsing from then ;) Glad you've solved the problem.