# Group by consecutive count Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by

Here's the data:

```
ID  Type
1   In
1   In
1   Out
1   In
2   Out
2   In
2   In
2   In
2   Out
```

**Question:** I want a pandas query that can fetch me the IDs where "In" appears more than 2 times consecutively. So, if I run the query on the above data it should only fetch me 2.

Comment: why are you using pandas?

Comment: I think the best is delete question, and create new with some sample in plain text (not html) and some code, what do you try. Then you get multiple nice answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Type'].agg(lambda x: (x=='In').rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.all()).max())
Out[34]: 
ID
1    0.0
2    1.0
Name: Type, dtype: float64
```

It will return 1 for the groups that meet your criterion, 0 otherwise.

It first groups by ID and takes the Type column. For your example, it has two groups: `{1: ['In', 'In', 'Out', 'In'], 2: ['Out', 'In', 'In', 'In', 'Out']}`. For each group (`x`), it first creates a boolean series `x=='In'`. The series are `[True, True, False, True]` and `[False, True, True, True, False]`. Now, on those series, it applies the rolling function. It takes three at a time and evaluates `x.all()`. For the first group, the first three (`[True, True, False]`) and the second three (`[True, False, True]`) returns False because all three should be True. The maximum of these two False's is 0. For the second group, the rolling method will produce (`[False, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, False]`) so for the second one `x.all()` will be True and therefore the maximum will be 1.

`Series.rolling()` was introduced in pandas 0.18 I believe. For earlier versions, you can use:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Type'].agg(lambda x: pd.rolling_apply(x=='In', 3, lambda x: x.all()).max())
```

Comment: it says `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling'` I am on Python 2.7 anaconda dist

Comment: You might need to update pandas. You need v18.0. Or you can use rolling_apply.

Comment: Thanks mr @ayhan! Everything worked like magic... I wish this question will be protected though. Care to explain this answer just so it remains documented?

Comment: Sure, I added an explanation. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: That's as clear as it can get! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong tool.
I would recommend using an xml parser try [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058599/how-to-get-a-nested-element-in-beautiful-soup) and if for some unknown reason you still plan to store the html data in pandas I think you could iterate through those rows and parse them.
However I recommend you just fetch it and parse it elsewhere.
As for the nested tags, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058599/how-to-get-a-nested-element-in-beautiful-soup) might be useful

EDIT: you edited your question so here is a new answer
In order to select duplicate rows try this:

```
df.groupby([...]).filter(lambda df:df.shape[0] > 1)
```

Comment: Very sorry guys! newbie you see! I have the data in rows and columns and I was not sure how to represent the data...

Comment: let me know if this new edit works, consider accepting if it did