# Why does soup.find_all always return an empty string even though there are very clearly tags present within the specified class?

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup

```
page = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5')
print(soup.prettify())
soup.find_all('a', class_='RNNXgb')
```

I chose a random class name, one that clearly has html tags present within it but I always get an empty string every time i try to parse. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using curly braces after the 'a'. I switched out the class name, since I didn't see anything on Google.com with that class name:
`test = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'gb1'})`

Comment: I get a syntax error when I use the curly braces. Also, can I parse data from any tag no matter how deeply nested they are? I found the RNNXgb tag fairly deep within the HTML code of google.

Comment: can you show exactly what you are typing to get a syntax error, and the version of Python you are using?  Also, the RNNXgb class is a div tag, not an a, which could be part of your problem. Also, you will need to use a for loop to get nested elements within the HTML tree. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058599/how-to-get-a-nested-element-in-beautiful-soup