BeautifulSoup4: How to find all tables that have a distant descendant with certain text in it?
I am trying to scrape pages of a site that have information organized in <table>s with nested tables. In particular, the specific tables i want all have a nested <table> with a <tr> containing a <th> with a <span> with certain text in it.
Something like this:
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            ...
            <tr>
              <th>
                <span>Text that should be in each table i want to get</span>
              </th>
            ...

In other words, how can I do a search for a tag that contains certain text but get a distant ancestor of that tag? The use case is that i will need a lot of the data in the outermost table depicted here, but there is no attribute of that parent table that I can search for, so i need to search based on its descendants.
I have tried just searching for  but there are so many tables as the page is organized almost entirely with them, so it's hard to pick through and find exactly what I need. I'm hoping to find a way to search for a tag where a descendant fulfills a condition. Even better if i can check for a descendant at a certain depth (e.g. if i know the span is at that depth from the table, can I search for that?) as the outermost table will have all of these tables inside it and thus also fulfill the condition of some descendant having the desired text.

Help us to help you - Please provide also for future questions the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Providing an url as well as an expected result would be also great. Thanks

possible something like this if you know the structure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058599/how-to-get-a-nested-element-in-beautiful-soup otherwise maybe consider looking at xpaths (although bs4 doesn't support such there are other packages that could extend the feature set)

You can use find_all() to work your way down the tree, looking for the descendant tags which have the text. Afterwards use find_parents() to work your way back up the tree, looking at the tag's parents.
Here is the outline of the code to find the heading text on a page and look for its parent table tags.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re

PAGE_URL = "https://..."
FIXED_HEADING_PATTERN = "Fixed text"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(PAGE_URL).read())
pattern = re.compile(FIXED_HEADING_PATTERN)

headings = soup.find_all("span", text=pattern)

# For each heading found create a list of it's parent tables
for heading in headings:
    parent_tables = [t for t in heading.find_parents("table")]
    # Use parent_tables


In newer code avoid old syntax findAll() instead use find_all() or select() with css selectors - For more take a minute to check docs

Thanks for catching FindAll, my fingers were on auto pilot.
